# If Snoke was a clone, who was the source?

Tags: star-wars, clones, the-rise-of-skywalker, snoke

After reading this question ([Was Snoke an individual or a puppet?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/225236/was-snoke-an-individual-or-a-puppet)), the follow-up thought occurred to me that if Snoke is a clone, his source DNA had to originate from somewhere, so where did it come from?

> It would be easy to assume that Snoke is a clone of Palpatine, but I find that highly unlikely for two reasons.  First, even in his disfigured stated, he looks nothing like Palpatine. Second, Palpatine has attempted to remain hidden for over 20 years and if he had a clone (or clones) running around that look like him, people would probably get the picture that he's pulling the strings.  Having a clone that originated from a different human source makes sense, especially if it were genetically modified (or whatever) to be force attuned, as to be trained in using the force.

So, if Snoke is a clone, who (or what) was his DNA source, even if it were modified to make him force-aware?

Comment: @Mods, FYI, I've tried to keep this spoiler-free, but I can understand if you feel this question reveals to much.  However, considering the trailers for the film, I don't feel the non-spoiler-wrapped portions really reveal anything beyond which we could all infer from the story so far and, again, what we've learned from the trailers.

Comment: Palpatine was a Snokloner.

Comment: He is a clone of the Eraserhead baby!

Comment: I thought Palpatine simply created him using Sith powers, i don't recall cloning being mentioned

Comment: He could have been the original source as well, just with a lot of manipulation to get the desired results after all isn't that what they did for the storm troopers?

Comment: I'm going to guess the clone was from Jar-Jar Binks

Comment: @KyleWilliamson You're going to give Jar-Jar *that* much credit?

Comment: Gollum of course.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps it's Hego Damask DNA, otherwise known as Darth Plagueis. According to the [fandom page](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darth_Plagueis/Legends), in the Legends section there's a line stating

> The Sith spirit urns in Darth Sidious's collection, one of which contained Darth Plagueis's remains

I do realize this is part of Legends but with this explication we can assume Palatine had access to his former masters remains. The remains were in there for quite some time so perhaps that's the reason for Snoke's deformation?

Damask was also strong in the Force but the main thing that sticks out to me is Snoke's size. Damask was a Muun and they seemed taller than the average human.

Again this is just a theory and a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any answer has been given as to Snoke's origins, other than that he was made by Palpatine and there are multiple copies of his body in Palpatine's laboratory. It seems reasonable that he's just a flesh puppet Palpatine imbued with his own powers, which allowed Palpatine to rule the First Order from a safe distance while his real body recuperated on Exegol. It would also explain where there isn't an army of Snoke clones, since if Snoke drew his power from Palpatine, he couldn't make endless copies.

Answer (score 0):

There's an implication in the movie that Snoke is a clone of Sheev Palpatine.

1. Palpatine notes that he has been kept alive by "unnatural means" around the time they talk about Snoke. They are juxtaposed such that it could be possible that Palpatine was culling Snoke clones to harvest parts for himself
2. Who better to run his First/Last order than a clone of himself?
3. Snoke is an adept Force user (he overwhelms both Rey and Kylo Ren at the same time in *The Last Jedi*). His skills seem to rival that of Palpatine himself. The only other Force users we've seen with that kind of skill are the Skywalkers, Yoda and maybe Mace Windu.